# How to use else if in html?

Tags: php, joomla

I am using joomla and i want to do this with my template!

```
<html>
   <?php if ($this['config']->get('home')) : ?>
      <div class="home">
       Some content
      <div>
   <?php else : ?>
      <div class="page">
       Some other content
      <div>
   <?php else if ($this['config']->get('blog')) : ?>
      <div class="blog">
       Some other blog content
      <div>
   <?php endif; ?>
</html>
```

My problem is that i can't use multiple ( else if ) in this  code .

lets say like this:

```
<html>
   <?php if ($this['config']->get('home')) : ?>
      <div class="home">
       Some content
      <div>
   <?php else if ($this['config']->get('page')) : ?>
      <div class="page">
       Some other content
      <div>
   <?php else if ($this['config']->get('blog')) : ?>
      <div class="blog">
       Some other blog content
      <div>
   <?php endif; ?>
</html>
```

my english is not that impressiv so i hope you understand me

Answer (score 2):

You no need to use else if in last

```
<html>
   <?php if ($this['config']->get('home')) : ?>
      <div class="home">
       Some content
      <div>
   <?php else if ($this['config']->get('page')) : ?>
      <div class="page">
       Some other content
      <div>
   <?php else  : ?>
      <div class="blog">
       Some other blog content
      <div>
   <?php endif; ?>
</html>
```